# How to display this JavaScript message in my webOS app?

Tags: javascript, html, webos, palm

I am writing a webOS app and I want the following code to present a "Good Morning!" message. What code do I need to put in my Main-scene.html file and what else do I need in the Main-assistant.js file to make this work?

Many thanks in advance.

```
MainAssistant.prototype.welcomeMessage = function(){
datetoday = new Date();
timenow = datetoday.getTime();
datetoday.setTime(timenow);
thehour = datetoday.getHours();
if (thehour > 18) 
    display = "Evening";
else 
    if (thehour > 12) 
        display = "Afternoon";
    else 
        display = "Morning";
var greeting = ("Good " + display + "!");
document.write(greeting);
};
```

All the best

David

Answer (score 0):

I don't know when the *welcomeMessage* method will be called, but if it's after the document has finished loading then it is closed. Calling *document.write* then will call *document.open*, which completely clears the document. Likely you have an element that the message should be written into, much better to use the load or DOMReady events (or whatever is available on WebOS).

Consider a much simpler form of the function and don't forget to declare variables to limit their scope to only what is necessary:

```
  var tod = ['morning','morning','afternoon','evening'];
  var now = new Date();
  var greeting = 'Good ' + (tod[now.getHours()/6|0]) + '!';
```

If you want a library, try [myLibrary](http://www.cinsoft.net/mylib.html). No, it's not **my** Library, it's your library when you use it. You can create a customised core and just the DOM ready part that is quite small and the code quality is excellent.